# telnet connection closes

Tags: tcp, telnet

I am running hdfs in one machine. I am trying to write into hdfs from my second machine. I got connection refused error and got this link in the error itself: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I checked for ping and traceroute and all. Everything works. But telnet to that server and port fails:

```
  telnet localhost 8020

   Trying ::1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The connection is closed immediately (less than 2s).

Some of the SO answers suggested other users to use 127.0.0.1 instead localhost.

```
  telnet 127.0.0.1 8020

  Same as above output
```

So I checked if anything is listening at 8020,

```
  netstat -plten | grep 8020

  tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8020       :::*  LISTEN    0  1331261    10940/java
```

So I checked whether the telnet program is working

```
  telnet google.com 80

  GET / HTTP/1.1
  host: test.com

  [twice enter]
```

It works. Similar to this, i would like to provide input and get response. What is the problem here? Am i wrong? If so, please correct me

Comment: Your webserver(?) is probably closing the connection since you're not sending fast enough.

Comment: No, It is closing IMMEDIATELY. Not even 2 Secs

Comment: Does service accept telnet connection always ? It can reject telnet request as well. Why would you try telnet is the question and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: [Link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused) I am running hdfs in one machine. I am trying to write into hdfs from my second machine. I got connection refused error and got this link in the error itself. I checked for ping and traceroute and all. everything works. But telent to that server and port fails

Comment: Yes, i used lsof -i :8020, it says docker. It's right only

Comment: How is the server configured? Maybe it accepts connections only from some IP addresses and you didn't include localhost.